# Windows 10 からの同時リクエスト数の制限はいくつか

Tags: windows-10

マルチスレッドでwebスクレイピングをしているのですが、リクエストに失敗してしまうことが多いです。
Windows 10の同時リクエスト数制限はいくつなんでしょうか？
また、変更することはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 対象サイトの管理者には許可を得てますか？ クローラを使って某図書館サイトにアクセスしたら業務妨害とかで逮捕された事例があるので甘く考えない方がいいと思います。

Comment: 実際に試したコードや、失敗時の情報 (エラーメッセージ等) がもしあれば質問に含めた方が具体的な回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 「リクエストに失敗してしまう」とは具体的にはどういうことでしょうか？

Comment: リクエストに失敗というのはタイムアウトです。

Comment: 失敗の原因がタイムアウトであるなら、同時リクエスト数を増やすことが必ずしも根本的な解決になるとは限らない気がします。(相手先への負荷は考慮した上で) シングルスレッドでも確実にリクエストが完了することをまずは目指すべきじゃないでしょうか。(タイムアウトまでの時間を伸ばしてみる等)

Comment: シングルスレッドでのリクエストは成功しています。他のサーバーに複数のリクエストを送るプログラムを同時実行しており、増え過ぎるとほとんどがタイムアウトしてしまうようなのです。

Comment: 何を使って HTTPリクエストしているのか (手製のスクリプトか何かか, あるいは Windows API叩いてるのか)。「他のサーバーに複数のリクエスト」とはサーバーが複数なのか, 一つのサーバーに複数リクエストなのか … そのあたりの情報を質問に付け加えるとよいかもです。あと問題がタイムアウトであることも。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ご質問の本文から特定はできませんが、ポートの枯渇問題というのはよくある話なので、こちらのトラブルシューティングを参照してください。
[ポートの枯渇問題のトラブルシューティング](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-port-exhaust)

問題が再現しているときに、netstat・イベントログを確認する。

Comment: 「ポートの枯渇」とかはではないと思います。HTTP 1.1 仕様では同時接続は 2 つまでとなっています。例えば、HttpWebRequest を使った場合にもその制約が適用されます。

Comment: スクレイピングは、サイトの管理者に許可を得ているとか、規約に従って専用の API にアクセスしているとかでなければ、迷惑行為になるかもしれない、回答するのは迷惑行為の手助けをすることになるかもしれません。

Comment: そのコメントは、1プロセスでやっている場合の話ではないでしょうか。ま、質問の情報が足りませんので、なんとも。

Comment: 技術的な話であって、私の回答に対して迷惑行為になるかも、というのは無用な心配です。質問に対する懸念のコメントは、仰る通りだと思います。

Comment: metaに参考になるものがありました。以後、コメント不要です。  https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1633/

Comment: コメント欄は議論をする場ではないため、この会話をチャットに移動しました： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139988/discussion-on-answer-by-htb-windows-10-

Comment: そのコメントは、1プロセスでやっている場合の話ではないでしょうか。←意味が分かりません。質問には「マルチスレッドで」と書‌​いてありますよ。例えばですが、マルチスレ‌​ッドの .NET アプリででマルチに（同時に） HttpWebRequest を使った場合、同時接続数は 2 です。 <= これは残しておくべき

Answer (score 2):

htbさんの回答はWindowsのポート枯渇の観点で書かれていますが、WebSurferさんもコメントされているようにWindows側はポート枯渇していない可能性が高いです。

それとは別に昨今の日本のインターネット環境では **IPoE**（IPv4 over IPv6） が普及しています。IPoEの場合、実際のIPv4ポートを管理しているのはISP側であり、ポート枯渇対策のためISP側が同時コネクション数を制限している場合があります。制限方法もISPによって様々ですが、クライアントから見てレスポンスが遅く異様に待たされることもあります。その場合にクライアントはタイムアウトと判断することもあるかもしれません。

IPoEの同時コネクション数制限か否かは、接続方式をPPPoEに切り替えることで判断できます。

（FTPは1ファイル1コネクションなので、ftpクライアント開発では簡単に枯渇します…）

---

何にせよ、この質問は[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/4236)であり、推測を重ねた上で質問（Windows 10の同時リクエスト数制限）するのではなく、具体的に起こった問題（リクエストの失敗）を尋ねるべきです。